# Are games/programs compiled for multiple architectures?

Tags: compilation, cpu-architecture

This might be a big broad and somewhat stupid, but it is something I've never understood.

I've never dealt with code that needs to be compiled except Java, which I guess falls between two chairs, so here goes.

I don't understand how games and programs are compiled. Are they compiled for multiple architectures? Or are they compiled during installation (it does not look that way)?

As far as I've understood, code needs to be compiled based on the local architecture in order to make it work. Meaning that you can't compile something for AMD and "copy" the binaries and execute them on a computer running Intel (or similar).

Is there something I've misunderstood here, or does they use an approach which differs from the example I am presenting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD and Intel are manufacturers. You might be thinking of amd64 (also known as x86_64) versus x86. x86_64 is, as the name suggests, based on x86.

Computers running a 64-bit x86_64 OS can normally run x86 apps, but the reverse is not true. So one possibility is to ship 32 bit x86 games, but that limits the amount of RAM that can be accessed per process. That might be OK for a game though.

---

A bigger issue is shipping for different platforms, such as Playstation and (Windows) PC. The Playstation not only has a completely different CPU architecture (Cell), but *a different operating system.*

In this case you can't simply cross-compile - and that is because of the operating system difference. You have to have two separate versions of the game - sharing a bunch of common code and media files (also known as assets) - one version for PC and one for Playstation.

You could use Java to overcome that problem, in theory... but that only works when a JVM is available for all target platforms. Also, there is now fragmentation in the Java market, with e.g. Android supporting a different API from JME. And iPhones and iPads don't support Java at all.

Many games publishers do not in fact use Java. An exception is Mojang.

Comment: In this situation you actually usually cross-compiles. Meaning that you compile binaries for one platform (Architecture/OS combo) on another platform. IE. you compile binaries for Android (ARM) on (X86). And I would assume binaries for playstations are also compiled on X86 platforms.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant you can't _simply_ cross-compile your existing app for another platform.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. It makes a lot sense and I see now that I've misunderstood how compiling source code works. Thanks!